# How to set resoutlion for AWS media convert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-media-convert

I was planning on using aws mediaconvert to make multiple different copies of videos with different resolution via aws sdk and I noticed in the example that the Resolution was not included, so I how would I be able to specify it (tell it to do 1920 by 1080 for example)?

```
            "Outputs" => [
                [
                    "VideoDescription" => [
                         ??? "Resolution" => "DEFAULT", ???
                        "ScalingBehavior" => "DEFAULT",
                        "TimecodeInsertion" => "DISABLED",
                        "AntiAlias" => "ENABLED",
                        "Sharpness" => 50,
                        "CodecSettings" => [
                            "Codec" => "H_264",
                            "H264Settings" => [
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but if you look at the job request json it has "width" and "height" parameters. These will be in the "VideoDescription" object. You can try and see if that works:

```
"VideoDescription": {
    "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
    "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
    "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
    "Sharpness": 50,
    "CodecSettings": {
        "Codec": "H_264",
        "H264Settings": {
            "InterlaceMode": "PROGRESSIVE",
            "NumberReferenceFrames": 3,
            "Bitrate": 5000000
            ...
        }
    },
    "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
    "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
    "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
    "ColorMetadata": "INSERT",
    "Width": 1920,
    "Height": 1080
}
```

Comment: Oh! I complete missed that, thanks, I'll look into it and soon accept your answer.